# Using Unicodes in Swift Regular Expression

Tags: swift, regex, unicode

I am trying to match a regex pattern in a string in Swift. When I use the actual characters in regex pattern, it works as expected. However, I use Unicode versions of the same characters in regex, it does not work as expected. Could you please help me with what is wrong here. I need to use regex with Unicode.

Code:

```
var input = "一" // u{4E00}

extension String {
    var patternMatchesWithUnicode: Bool {
        //doesnt work
        return self.range(of: #"[\u{4E00}-\u{9FFF}]"#, options: .regularExpression) != nil
    }
    var patternMatchesWithString: Bool {
        //works
        return self.range(of: #"[一-鿿]"#, options: .regularExpression) != nil
    }
}

print(input.patternMatchesWithString)
print(input.patternMatchesWithUnicode)
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```swift
extension String {
    var patternMatchesWithUnicode: Bool {
        return self.range(of: #"[\u4E00-\u9FFF]"#, options: .regularExpression) != nil
    }
}
```

These will also work:

```swift
return self.range(of: #"[\x{4E00}-\x{9FFF}]"#, options: .regularExpression) != nil
return self.range(of: #"[\U00004E00-\U00009FFF]"#, options: .regularExpression) != nil
```

Swift regex flavor is [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp), see the excerpt from the docs page:

> `\uhhhh`  - Match the character with the hex value `hhhh`.
> `\Uhhhhhhhh` - Match the character with the hex value `hhhhhhhh`. Exactly eight hex digits must be provided, even though the largest Unicode code point is `\U0010ffff`.
> `\x{hhhh}` - Match the character with hex value `hhhh`. From one to six hex digits may be supplied.
> `\xhh` - Match the character with two digit hex value `hh`.

Comment: Nice. It worked and I settled with \uhhhh. +1 for sharing ICU docs.